# Changing the Order/Structure (r x c) of a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to change the order of my df in terms of rows and columns. Assume I have already generated a df through the use of pd.DataFrame but the df given to me is n-rows and a single column. I would like to manipulate it to example, give me 5 x 3 or 2 x 5 structure. I have been searching high and low for this, help !
E.g

```
   0
0  1
1  3
2  5
```

The current shape is a 3 x 1. What if I would like to do a 1 x 3 or 5 x 3 for larger dataframes etc?

Comment: Can you please, give an example of you dataFrame and explain the logic of the structure you are expecting ?

Comment: done ! Edited my example.

Comment: 3x1 to 1x3 you can do `df.T`.

Comment: but what if i want to manipulate larger data? E.g create a random df with 5 x 8 shape?

Comment: I don't get your question, whats stopping you to create a 5x8 df?

Comment: The default shape that it returns to me is in a single column~ I think Rajesh below is answering it, thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An nXm dataframe can be converted to mXn dataframe using transpose, where n is the number of rows and m is the number of columns

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html

```
>>> df
   0
0  1
1  3
2  5

>>> df.T
   0  1  2
0  1  3  5
```

Comment: Say if I have an initial df with 40 data as 40 x 1. How do I transpose to a 5 x 8 data?